# How to replicate such an halftone/bitmap visual effect?

Tags: texture, halftone

I'm looking to try to replicate the halftone/bitmap effect on the t-shirt reference, so as to do my owns ~ in time ~ with such cool visual effects :))
[image: tshirt]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: basically i have tried to do such an LCD effect so far but in vain.. like my halftone don't look like the one in tshirt.. as can be seen here https://imgur.com/gallery/YizvQ8n here :))

Comment: That's actually a good path. Simply looks like you need to reduce as much of the mid-tones as you can first.

Comment: Note that (regardless of the method chosen to make the patterning) after you boost the contrast to get rid of the mid-tones as Scott suggests, you might want to then mask or paint out areas that you are not interested in having in the final image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a halftone. It's a dither pattern.

You can use software such as GIMP or Photoshop to do something similar. Convert the image to Greyscale mode, then convert to Indexed mode, set the number of colours to 2. Use one of the colour dithering patterns. The example below was done in GIMP.

[image]

Comment: you're the goat. greatest of all times foreal. you just never miss!